# media9 / APlayer: Unwanted Lag/Pause/Delay When Clicking For The Next Slide (beamer)

Tags: media9

- I embedded a small mp3 file using the `media9` (`APlayer.swf` player).
- I use the `beamer` document class.
- The sound file plays well -- but when it's over and I click in order to get to the next slide then it takes a couple of seconds (4-5 s) before the slide actual changes.
- I tried it on two Win 10 computers.
- Is this just the way it is?
- Has somebody encountered a similar problem in the past?

MWE (on [**ShareLaTeX**](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58bd598e31d8e1357f5d05b8))

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\includemedia[
addresource=2To2Sound.mp3,
flashvars={source=2To2Sound.mp3&autoplay},
transparent,
]{Click Here!}{APlayer.swf} (Somehow you need to click twice\ldots)

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Next Frame Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll test this tonight. No AR available here.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks. At the moment I'll use the multimedia package instead (but without actual embedding).

Comment: @Manuel : FYI, File-Upload is evil, it tried to make me download an EXEcutable (`2To2Sound.mp3.exe`), possibly malware. Please don't use it in future postings. I replaced your links by a public ShareLaTeX project.

Comment: @AlexG Ok. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration variable for auto-play is wrong, it must read `autoPlay=true`. Therefore, the sound does not start playing after activation by single click.

For testing, I open the PDF in AR DC (Windows) and with the current FlashPlayer (for Firefox) 24,0,0,221 installed.

For me, with the correct setting, auto-play and going to the next slide work smoothly.

Open on [**ShareLaTeX:**](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58bd4e5f31d8e1357f5d0366)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}

\includemedia[
addresource=2To2Sound.mp3,
flashvars={source=2To2Sound.mp3&autoPlay=true},
transparent,
]{Click Here!}{APlayer.swf}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Next Frame Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! On **Adobe Acrobat X Pro**I still see the same problem as described in the question. On **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC** it works well.